# LINQ to XML file

Tags: xml, linq

I have XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Table>
  <User>
    <Danik>ID15101639</Danik>
    <ID15101639>Danik</ID15101639>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Marcel>ID29101645</Marcel>
    <ID29101645>Marcel</ID29101645>
  </User>
</Table>
```

And I need to search in this file - if user imput name like "Danik" (textbox1.Text) it should show him "ID15101639".

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            jmeno = textBox1.Text;
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load("seznam.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> Table = xelement.Elements();
            foreach (var User in Table)
            {
                overeni = User.Element(jmeno).Value;
                textBox2.Text = overeni;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work properly. Could you please advice where is the issue?

It show error on line 12 - overeni = User.Element(jmeno).Value;
Error: The using directive for System.Linq appeared previosly in this namespace.

Comment: How does it not work properly? An error? Wrong result?

Comment: Good question, you may be should also tell the issue = the problem

Comment: I am sorry - it doesn't found the name in XML file.

Comment: I have change code:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

jmeno = textBox1.Text;
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load("seznam.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> Table = xelement.Elements();
            foreach (var User in Table)
            {
                overeni = User.Element(jmeno).Value;
                textBox2.Text = overeni;



When I run code it shows error in line - overeni = User.Element(jmeno).Value;
Error = the using directive for System.Linq appeared previosly in this namespace.

Comment: I have maybe another useful information. If I use in code: MessageBox.Show (User.Element(jmeno).Value);

It does show me correct information in message box but just after that it show "An unhandled exception of type "Sysetm.NullReferenceException" occurred in windowsformapplication.exe. Additional informtion: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Again for line: MessageBox.Show (User.Element(jmeno).Value);

Comment: Maybe the problem could be here: string overeni; There should be something different than string ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way instead to avoid that null reference exception :

```cs
//filter only <Tables> having child element <{jmeno}>
//then return that <{jmeno}> element
XElement User =  xelement.Elements()
                         .Where(o => o.Element(jmeno) != null)
                         .Select(o => o.Element(jmeno))
                         .FirstOrDefault();
if (User != null)
{
    overeni = User.Value;
    textBox2.Text = overeni;
}
```